# new-handler function invocation

Tags: c++, new-operator

Could anyone provide an example in which allocation is fail. I.e. I just want to invoke new_handler function I've cited:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

void *p = operator new(0);

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "something" << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::set_new_handler(foo);
    std::get_new_handler()(); //Ok, but I want that the function invoke as memory allocation fail handler
}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/set_new_handler

Comment: On e.g., linux, allocation by default never fails.  If the system runs out of real memory, it will pick a process and kill it to free some up.  So your question hinges on which OS you are using.

Comment: @goldilocks I'm using linux mint 14. Here is the example in action: http://ideone.com/DwEVXI

Comment: I spoke in haste.  AFAICT it won't fail because the system is out of memory, but it will fail if the process is out of *address space*.  On a 64-bit system this is probably around 3 GB -- here's a succinct investigation: http://scvalex.net/posts/6/  Meaning, his may happen even if you have enough physical GB, and may not happen even though you do not.